# getting issue on interscore contract burn of single asset

Tags: smartpy

I have a function on my contract that calls the fa2 contract burn method of singleAsset provided by the fa2 library.

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def burn_test2(self,fa2_address, value):
        burn_args_type = sp.TList(sp.TRecord(from_=sp.TAddress, token_id=sp.TNat, amount=sp.TNat))
        burn_entry_point = sp.contract(burn_args_type, fa2_address, "burn").open_some()
        burn_args = [sp.record(from_=sp.self_address, token_id=sp.nat(0), amount=value)]
        sp.transfer(burn_args, sp.tez(0), burn_entry_point)
```

Am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: What issue do you have or errors?